# How to send a from with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to send a from with `AJAX` and send its content fields in mail. In the code below i can't prevent the page from changing. How can i send the form without changing the page?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form action="mail.php" method="post" id="form">
     <input class="input field" type="text" id="name" name="lastname" placeholder="LAST NAME&#42;" required onblur="checkInput()">
      <input class="input field" type="text" id="firstName" name="firstname" placeholder="FIRST NAME&#42;" required onblur="checkInput()">
       <input class="input field" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-MAIL&#42;" required onblur="checkInput()">
       <textarea class="field fieldTextArea" id="content" name="content" placeholder="YOUR MESSAGE" required onblur="checkInput()"></textarea>

       <div id="submitContainer">
          <input class="button submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton">
        </div>
   </form>
                    
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          let formData = {
            name: $("lastname").val(),
            firstname: $("firstname").val(),
            email: $("email").val(),
            content: $("content").val(),
          };

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            encode: true,
          });

        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code for `mail.php` where i get the data to send it in an email with Sendgrid:

```
<?php

if(isset( $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['content'])) {
    $content = "You have a message from: . \n
    lastname: ".$_POST["lastname"]." \n
    firstname: ".$_POST["firstname"]."\n
    email: ".$_POST["email"]." \n
    content: ".$_POST["content"]."\n";

    sendEmail($content);

}
?>
```

Comment: try _name: $("input[name=lastname]").val(),_

Comment: Add a `return false;` at the end of the function. Check [Prevent form from submitting via event.preventDefault(); not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051128/prevent-form-from-submitting-via-event-preventdefault-not-working)